# Uncaught typeerror: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined in OpenLayers 2.12 using Google maps

Tags: google-maps, openlayers

Suddenly I am getting:

Uncaught typeerror: Cannot read property 'style' of undefined in OpenLayers.js Line 1063 when using Google maps. I don't get the error when using OpenStreetMaps. I am using OpenLayers 2.12 and Internet Explorer.

Since my code has not changed in a year or more I can only assume that something has changed in Google maps.

Has anyone else come across this error and found a solution?

Comment: Additional information: After the error reported above I am also getting:

Google Maps API warning; NoAPiKeys
Google Maps API warning: SensorNotRequired
Google Maps API warning: Retired version.

Comment: It may be related to deprecation of old versions of Internet Explorer. Have a look at https://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=9004.

Comment: Doesn't really sound like the same problem. And it turns out this is happening in chromium too.

Answer (score 0):

This turns out to have been the result of an apparent confluence of events.

1) Google appears to have started enforcing the use of an API key to access Google Maps. It was optional before but it now seems to be required. Using a key got rid of the NoApiKeys warning.

2) Google appears to have deprecated a lot of older versions of the API. I was using 3.9 and had to upgrade to 3.23 to get rid of the Retired Version error.

3) The Sensor parameter is no longer required but instead of being silently ignored it now causes a warning. Removing the Sensor parameter got rid of the SensorNotRequired warning.

4) Upgrading to 3.23 of the Google API caused 2.12 of OpenLayers to stop working. No more errors but no map either. I had to upgrade to 2.13.1 of OpenLayers to get things working again.